# そして、外国人が来たときの準備をしている近くの病院を地図で知らせます

Tags: sentence

> そして、**外国人が来たときの準備をしている近くの**病院を地図で知らせます。([source](http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10011217511000/k10011217511000.html))

It's basically the part in bold which I fail to integrate into the sentence.
I also feel a bit unsure about the use of the causative here.
However, first my attempt at translation of the sentence without the bold part:

> Furthermore...it makes the hospital aware (lets the hospital know) with the map.

When I try to integrate the bold part, I can't put the individual parts together. For example:

> 外国人が来たとき  の  準備をしている近く

Here, the first part, which gives a temporal information, is somehow an attribute of 病院

my attempt at full translation:

> Furthermore, with the map it makes the nearby hospital doing the preparations of the when the foreigner came aware.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the transitive verb 知らせる rather than the causative of 知る. It means ' to inform' The verb takes an object which is the thing you are being informed about. The person being informed is you, not the hospital.

> Using a map, it informs you of nearby hospitals which are prepared for when foreigners come.